# Не удаётся найти "libc.so.6" при запуске Python скрипта в Termux на Android

Tags: python, android, lib, обфускация, termux

Я обфусцировала свой `python` скрипт с помощью [pyarmor](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Для запуска скрипта нужна библиотека `_pytransform.dll`, при запуске через `termux` на `Android` — `_pytransform.os`. Я получила платформу на `Android` с помощью `distutils.util.get_platform()` — `linux-aarch64`. На [сайте](http://pyarmor.dashingsoft.com/downloads/platforms/) с разными сборками этой библиотеки скачала [Armv8 64-bit](http://pyarmor.dashingsoft.com/downloads/platforms/armv8.64-bit/_pytransform.so). При запуске обфусцированного скрипта теперь выводится ошибка `dlopen failed library libc.so.6 not found`. Как исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyarmor` умеет сам скачивать нужные библиотеки, для этого можно использовать:

```
pyarmor download android.aarch64 # или имя другой платформы
```

Тогда нужная библиотека появится в `~/.pyarmor/`.

Или сразу обфусцировать под конкретную платформу ([docs](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#obfuscating-scripts-with-different-features)):

```
pyarmor obfuscate --platform android.aarch64 ...
```

Comment: `Check license failed, Invalid input packet` из-за чего эта ошибка? В документации написано, что нужно проверить файл `license.lic`, но на Windows запускается без него, я так понимаю этот файл не нужен в случае если лицензия навсегда или просто её не использовать, тогда из-за чего ошибка